# How to retrieve Child value from Firebase and then refresh View using the value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to coding and only know a bit of Swift so far.
I have searched a lot, but I don't find this exact problem answered.

What I need to achieve is to reload various related items in the (detailed)view, when the user presses a button (with the "new" information the button gives).

So if I had:

"Title1"
"some info 1"
"button: "title3""

I want to press "button" and then get:

"Title3"
"some info 3"
"button: "title5""

My Firebase data structure is:

1. Results:

   - 1234

     - title1
     - some info 1
     - ++

I used to use Parse and there everything worked fine. In the below code I press a button, and then use the info on the button as the PFObject, run the query based on this PFObject and reload the view. Simple. (see Example1).

But in **Firebase** I am really struggling, (I think it has do do with my limited understanding of arrays and dictionaries...?) So I have sent the correct data from the tableview to the detailview, and everything is fine and works.

**But now I want to use "input from button2, fetch the corresponding data from Firebase and then refresh the view. (an attempt of some code in Example2)**
I realise that Parse and Firebase works quite differently, but I have a feeling I'm not that far off with example2, but I could be.

Any help is appreciated.

**Example 1. Old code using Parse**

```
/* 
   ==========================================================================================
 //MARK: START OF CODE THAT MAKES BUTTONS LOAD DATA FROM PARSE
 ==========================================================================================
 */
@IBAction func friend1(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Queries Parse to find the bottle that matches the button label when we press the button. Reloads the detail view with info from Parse
    let query = PFQuery(className:"whisky")
    query.whereKey("friendName1", equalTo: (friend1.titleLabel?.text)!)
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (newBottle: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && newBottle != nil {
            //write to array
            self.testBackButton.append(self.currentObject!["friendName1"] as! String!)
            //self.testBackButton.append((self.friend1.titleLabel?.text)!)
            print(self.testBackButton)
            //end write to array
            self.currentObject = newBottle
            self.viewDidLoad()
            //self.viewWillAppear(true)
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 2: attempt at doing the same from Firebase**

```
@IBAction func friend1(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("hubabba")
    //dbRef.child("Results").queryOrdered(byChild: "friendName2").queryEqual(toValue: "friendName2" as? String).observe(FIRDataEventType.childAdded, with: {(_ snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) ->
    dbRef.child("Results").queryEqual(toValue: "friendName2").observe(FIRDataEventType.childAdded, with: {(_ snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) ->Void in
        // This will fire for each matching child node.
        var score = snapshot.value
        //var newScore = score["friendName2"]
        print("Retrieved: \(score)")
        self.detailWhisky = score as? WhiskyItem
        self.viewDidLoad()
        /*
        //test -1
```

**Some supporting code from top of detailview**

```
var detailWhisky: WhiskyItem?
 //Firebase
 var dbRef:FIRDatabaseReference!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solved it:

```
@IBAction func friend2Button(_ sender: Any) {
    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "friendName1").queryEqual(toValue: self.friend2.titleLabel?.text).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            print("Ingen treff i soeket")
        } else {
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let newWhisky = WhiskyItem(snapshot: child as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                self.detailWhisky = newWhisky
                self.viewDidLoad()
            }}})}
```